# AutoCompleteTextField using setCompletionRenderer line breaks in long text not working

Tags: codenameone

Windows 10 Pro
NetBeans 12.3
Simulator is latest.

On July 19, 2016 at 8:07 pm a question was posed to you regarding making the popup list break lines for long text?
see https://www.codenameone.com/blog/dynamic-autocomplete.html

At that Time you responded "dynamic line breaking is problematic with renderers so that won’t work."

Has this changed?
Is there any way to span lines in the List?

I created a renderer with TextField and set setSingleLineTextArea and setGrowByContent true however The List object does not break lines.

Thoughts?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

With renederes getting multiple lines will always be problematic. You can just use a TextField and show an `InteractionDialog` popup below as you type. In it you can put whatever you want in terms of layout/components.

You can use the `DataChangeListener` to update the content of the dialog. This is obviously a bit more challenging than using the "simple" auto complete. But it gives you 100% control over the content.